# Tricky Button Moving Away when Mouseover in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I remember seeing some website or script on the web about this funny / tricky button: Basically it's a button that is impossible to click. When mouseover, it moves randomly away.

Can someone point me to a source or show me few line of code to do that? Preferably using jQuery.

Comment: Come on Mods , please close this question , He has got enough down-votes already !

Comment: I just arrived from google, and I do find this question useful :)

Comment: Same here, was useful.

Comment: Also found this useful - I think the mods are a tad draconian with their tactics sometime

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).css({
        left: (Math.random() * 200) + "px",
        top: (Math.random() * 200) + "px",
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9CDtE/4/

Comment: Simply for the reason that ,that guy was getting a lot of bad press, So atleast I would help him out . I was just being nice

Comment: Vote up for being nice! More people need to I guess.

Comment: p.s. I managed to click that button twice ;)

Comment: Well...congratulations...you got +10!

Comment: Thank you, nice of you to do that .

Comment: Needs higher random numbers, too easy to click ;) But yeah +1 because I was googling for this :p

Comment: +1 - I was also looking for this exact question ( even if it was only to annoy a staff member for a laugh )